# How to create multi level xml file

Tags: java, xml, file, document

I have a trouble in finding info about creating a multi level tags in xml file
for example i want next structure

```
<UserCards>
  <UserCard userCardId="171">
   <userName>somename</userName>
   <userSurname>somesurname</userSurname>
   <userAge>24</userAge>
   <userAdress>someadress</userAdress>
   <userPhone>223334455</userPhone>
     <CurrentBooks>
       <booName>someBookName</bookName>
     </CurrentBooks>
  </UserCard>
</UserCards>
```

I can create simple one level xml but how can I add new one?

```
 DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                DocumentBuilder docBulder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

                //root mainElement
                Document doc = docBulder.newDocument();
                Element rootElement = doc.createElement("UserCards");
                doc.appendChild(rootElement);

                //root Book
                Element UserCard = doc.createElement("UserCard");
                rootElement.appendChild(UserCard);
                ...  
                ...
                //write in a XMLFile
                TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
                Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
                DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
                StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File("Test/UserCards.xml"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems to me like you answered it yourself.... 
You can append elements to any element, not just the root.
You create all Elements by calling `doc.createElement("name")`
and append to the parent element of your choice:

```
Elmenet userName = doc.createElement("userName");
Text userNameText = doc.createTextNode("somename");
userName.appendChild(userNameText);
UserCard.appendChild(userName);
```

Comment: you are so right ... i was trying to do this but appended to wrong parent. THANK YO!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
            Element rootElement = doc.createElement("UserCards");
            doc.appendChild(rootElement);

            //root Book
            Element UserCard = doc.createElement("UserCard");
            UserCard.setAttribute("userCardId" , "171");
            Element userSurname = doc.createElement("userSurname");
            UserCard.appendChild(userSurname);

            Element userAge = doc.createElement("userAge");
            UserCard.appendChild(userAge);
            Element userAdress = doc.createElement("userAdress");
            UserCard.appendChild(userAdress);
            Element userPhone = doc.createElement("userPhone");
            UserCard.appendChild(userPhone);
            Element CurrentBooks = doc.createElement("CurrentBooks");
            Element booKName = doc.createElement("booKName");
            CurrentBooks.appendChild(booKName);
            UserCard.appendChild(CurrentBooks);
            rootElement.appendChild(UserCard);
```